# What are the most important scholarly resources for Latin and Greek historical linguistics?

Tags: etymology, language-evolution, resource-request, old-latin, research

When it comes to historical linguistics (history, prehistory, Indo-European studies, etymology) of Latin and Greek, what are the most important resources?
The resources can be historical grammars, etymological dictionaries, or anything similar.
I am not looking for a full bibliography, but useful reference material.

When you suggest a source, please indicate **how it is available** (online, in print, free, paid), **what it covers**, and **what makes it useful** in your opinion.

**Please give only one resource per answer.**
If you have many resources to suggest, give multiple answers — but read the other answers to avoid duplication.
This way people can vote on individual resources, causing the best ones to rise up and the worst ones to sink down, so that we can easily find the most useful resources.
If there are many resources listed in a single answer, it is hard to link the answer score to the quality of each listed item.

> **Note about resource questions:**
>   Broad resource questions like this are generally **not** allowed on this site.
>   The community chooses a select few to avoid an overflow of questions of this kind.
>   If you have an opinion on what resource questions should be asked next, post a suggestion in [this meta post](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/188/79) or vote the existing ones.
>   The ones to be asked will be chosen from that list according to their number of votes.
>   If you have ideas about listing resources on this site in general, you can contribute to [this meta discussion](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/177/79).
>
> In particular, if you would like to ask a similar resource request question, do **not** just ask it, but post a suggestion in the [mentioned meta post](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/188/79) instead.

Answer (score 6):

**De Vaan**'s *[Etymological Dictionary of Latin](http://www.brill.com/etymological-dictionary-latin)* is perhaps the most up to date one. He also bases his articles on the other main etymological dictionaries, like Walde-Hofmann and Ernout-Meillet. Sometimes I would have liked his articles to be a bit more expansive, but that would have required a lot more time to write. It is available on paper and [online](http://dictionaries.brillonline.com/latin).

Comment: It’s also available online (subscription required) http://dictionaries.brillonline.com/latin

Comment: @AlexB.: Ah, good to know. Too bad it's ridiculously expensive. One day of access for €12,50? And no doubt in large part funded by public money. (It's easy to find the PDF online.) But I'll put it in my answer.

Comment: Well, it is rather expensive but you get full access to **all** the etymological dictionaries published by Brill, with a wide range of search options. I recommend accessing it via an institution.

Comment: Another important note. As De Vaan himself says in the Introduction, this dictionary is "**not a complete etymological dictionary of Latin**. Its main aim ­­is to describe which roots and stems of the vocabulary of Latin and the other Italic languages are likely to have been inherited from Proto‑Indo‑European" [emphasis mine - Alex B.].

Comment: There seems to be [a paperback edition](http://www.brill.com/products/reference-work/etymological-dictionary-latin) for a quarter of the price. I don't know if there are any differences in content.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta♦: Ah, that is a huge difference! How odd.

Comment: No difference in content. I own it. There’s also a paperback edition of Beekes in 2 volumes.

Answer (score 4):

**Michael Weiss**'s [*Outline of the Historical and Comparative Grammar of Latin*](http://www.beechstave.com/weiss.html) is the most comprehensive, well-researched, and balanced historical grammar of Latin. There is [a website](http://ohcgl.blogspot.com/) with addenda and corrigenda maintained by [the author](http://linguistics.cornell.edu/michael-l-weiss). It is available on paper only; the second, corrected printing was released in 2011.

Answer (score 2):

For Greek, the best etymological dictionary is Robert Beekes' [*Etymological Dictionary of Greek*](https://brill.com/display/title/17726) in two volumes. This is to Greek what De Vaan is to Latin.

> Greek is among the most intensely and widely studied languages known. Since the publication of the last etymological dictionary of Greek, both the reconstruction of Proto-Indo-European, and our knowledge of the Greek substrate have led to numerous, often surprising new insights into the history and formation of the Greek vocabulary.
> This dictionary is a treasure trove covering 2000 years of Ancient Greek: from Mycenaean via Homer and the classical period to lexicographers, such as Hesychius (5th century A.D.).
>
> It consists of 7500 entries with thoroughly revised etymologies. Each entry gives clear information about the origin of the Greek word and its first date of attestation. It further provides all etymologically relevant variants, dialectal forms, derivatives, compounds, and bibliographical references.
> This dictionary is a truly indispensable tool for those in search of a deeper knowledge of the Greek vocabulary, its history and, therewith, a better understanding of the language.

As with De Vaan, it is also available in a paperback version.

Comment: Beekes is a valuable resource, but I think many people would quibble with describing it as "the best etymological dictionary" -- it has its flaws, most notoriously its Pre-Greek obsession, but also the fact that it sometimes presents idiosyncratic or Leiden-school-specific ideas as if they were communis opinio, and the entries can be overly brief. I always use it in conjuction with Chantraine's older dictionary.

Comment: That's fair. I was hasty in that remark. Certainly Chantraine is not replaced. I was just surprised Beekes (and Chantraine) were not mentioned here. Or Buck, for that matter.